# Sign of an integer polynomial at a real algebraic number

Tags: polynomials, rootfinding

Given $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, assumed to have a real root, let $r$  be the largest real root of $p$.  Now, given $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (without loss, of lesser degree than $p$), I would like to find out the sign of $f(r)$, using exact arithmetic.
Are there known algorithms for that?

Comment: Mmmmh, I don't understand which role $p$ is playing. Taking an arbitrary $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and setting $p=(X-a)^{n+1}$, we see that in this case your question becomes: let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $\leq n$. Find out the sign of $f(a)$ using exact arithmetic...Do  you know algorithms for this particular question ?

Comment: @GreginGre: I do not get your comment. Certainly when $r$ (or $a$, why the change of notation?) is an integer, then we can compute $f(a)$ exactly, it is an integer and its sign is no mystery. When $r$ is a general algebraic number seems another matter.

Comment: Yes, there are fairly simple algorithms. I suggest you study Lecture VII (Sturm theory) in Chee K. Yap, *Fundamental problems in algorithmic algebra*.

Comment: Thank you, the reference has it!